# React-konva move rectangle after rotating its div container

Tags: reactjs, konvajs

I'm using react-konva library to draw a fixed size rectangle. The rectangle has mouse drag events `onDragStart` and `onDragEnd` to re-position the rectangle upon dragging it. The event is working fine when the parent div angle (id="parentDiv") is 0 degree. When I try to rotate the div using CSS rotate, the rectangle event doesn't fire and the rectangle doesn't move at all!. I'm totally new to react-konva library and I can't find any case similar to mine.

The full code for this case (codesandbox) can be found at [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zx689v7v0p).

If you have any questions let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `Konva` do not support containers transformed with CSS. It breaks event detection. You can try to rotate a stage or a layer to achieve a similar result.

Comment: thanks sir for your answer, I tried your solution but unfortunately it didn't work. Do you have any other hacks?